# What Regex Pattern Should Be Used for 3 Possible Endings

Tags: c#, regex

This is a vexing one.  I had a block of text coming from a Beyond Compare script report.

```
Picture Compare
Produced: 10/17/2012 9:42:25 AM
Ignoring Unimportant
Left file: K:\HDA_FIN\user\JMan\All\A-0001.jpg     Right file: K:\HDA_FIN\user\JMan\All\B-0001.jpg
3454945 same pixel(s)
2154 ignored unimportant difference pixel(s)
2741 important difference pixel(s)
```

This repeats over and over as the script compares mated jpegs in the folder.  But some jpegs are 100% the same, so they have no ignored unimportant or important differences.  And some will have same differences and important differences, but no unimportants, and etc.  So I am trying to capture matches that start with "Picture Compare" and end with the LAST "pixel(s)" before the next "Picture Compare" starts again.

**What I have tried**:

What is am doing not is an ugly method: I use a stream reader, and while !EndOfStream, I perform sr.ReadLine() and add each line to a List.  I then use a for loop to iterate through the list and apply a series of if statements to determine whether the current string in the loop and the next few ahead match what I am looking for, and if so, I bind them to an object.  But surely Regex is much simpler.

```
    var lineByLine = new List<string>();
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        sb.AppendLine(line);
        if (line.Trim().Length > 0)  // && !line.Contains("picture-report layout"))
        {
            lineByLine.Add(line);
        }
    }

    Contents = sb.ToString();

    //get the report blocks


    for (int i = 0; i < lineByLine.Count; i++)
    {
        Block block;
        string[] lines = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };

        //does line contain pic compare? if so, this is the start of an object
        if (lineByLine[i].Contains("Picture Compare"))
        {
            lines[0] = lineByLine[i]; //start line
            block = new Block();
            lines[1] = lineByLine[i + 1]; //produces
            lines[2] = lineByLine[i + 2]; //subheading
            if (lineByLine[i + 3].Contains("Left"))
            {
                lines[3] = lineByLine[i + 3]; //file
                if (lineByLine[i + 4].Contains("same pixel(s)"))
                {
                    lines[4] = lineByLine[i + 4]; //same
                    if (lineByLine[i + 5].Contains("ignored unimportant"))
                    {
                        lines[5] = lineByLine[i + 5];
                        if (lineByLine[i + 6].Contains(" important difference"))
                        {
                            lines[6] = lineByLine[i + 6];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (lineByLine[i + 4].Contains("ignored unimportant"))
                {
                    lines[5] = lineByLine[i + 4];
                    if (lineByLine[i + 5].Contains(" important difference"))
                    {
                        lines[6] = lineByLine[i + 5];
                    }
                }
                else if (lineByLine[i + 4].Contains(" important difference"))
                {
                    lines[6] = lineByLine[i + 4];
                }
            }
            Blocks.Add(new Block(lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3], lines[4], lines[5], lines[6]));
        }
    }

}
finally
{
    sr.Close();
}
```

This works, but I am trying to refactor and make it cleaner.  I tried this:

```
 var matches = Regex.Matches(cr.Contents, "(Picture Compare)(.*?)(pixel)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

-but it stops at same pixels in all cases.  I need something greedier.  Any ideas?

Comment: What values do you actually want?

Comment: Each match should be a block that starts with Picture Compare and ends right before the next Picture Compare.  Each block can have either 5, 6 or 7 "lines", where the string has a line terminator.

Comment: Also, you should set the option to MultiLine, not SingleLine.

Comment: Multiline returns just the first line, Picture Compare, not the entire block. It's counter-intuitive, but SingleLine is most appropriate in this multiline string. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding the end you could try to find the next start:

```
@"Picture Compare(?:(?!Picture Compare).)*"
```

This matches `Picture Compare` and then as many characters as possible, as long as they don't start a new `Picture Compare` (this is what the negative lookahead is for). This should simply give you all those blocks.

Then on each of those blocks, you can do a lot simpler scanning to get the values you are interested in (unfortunately, I don't know which ones that are, otherwise I might have another regex for those as well `:P`).

Comment: That does it, thank you.  Negative lookahead is now in my utility belt.  Thanks again.  And yes, within each block I can parse each line, like for extracting the numbers used for determining a differential percentage to be applied to each pair of images.  Thanks!

Comment: Positive lookahead also works 
    "(Picture Compare)(.*?)(?=Picture Compare|\\Z)"

Comment: @Gebb good catch! It probably amounts to the same work for the regex engine, but it's good to note.

Comment: That is handy too!  Thx @Gebb

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex pattern

```
Picture Compare\n?(?:(?!Picture Compare)[^\n]*\n?)*
```

so you read line `Picture Compare` and all following lines that do not start with `Picture Compare`

Comment: This didn't work from me like m. buettner's solution, and I am curious as to why not. I am going to ponder it.

Comment: @GrayFox374 - Solution of m. buettner is slow, as it goes character by character. Mine goes line by line, is much faster and works properly - see http://ideone.com/9lOw8Z